# Add icon to rcp application

Tags: icons, eclipse-rcp, rcp

What is the code to add to the Exit menu (file>exit) to insert an icon in the

-`ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java`

```java
public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor {

    private IWorkbenchAction exitAction;

    public ApplicationActionBarAdvisor(IActionBarConfigurer configurer) {
        super(configurer);
    }

    protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {

        exitAction = ActionFactory.QUIT.create(window);
         exitAction.setImageDescriptor(Activator.getImageDescriptor("/icons/download.png"));
        register(exitAction);

    }

    protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {

        MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File",
        IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_FILE);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
         menuBar.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);


        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is your action bar advisor for your RCP. Since this is something you have written we need to see how you are creating the menu items before we can possibly advise. Show your code.

Comment: public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor {
 private IWorkbenchAction exitAction;
 public ApplicationActionBarAdvisor(IActionBarConfigurer configurer) {
  super(configurer);}
 protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
  exitAction = ActionFactory.QUIT.create(window);
 register(exitAction);}
 protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {
  MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File",IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_FILE);
  menuBar.add(fileMenu);
  fileMenu.add(exitAction);
 }}

Comment: Edit the question to add the code rather than putting unreadable code in a comment.

Comment: Done, sorry i'm new here.

Answer (score 2):

Image paths should be relative to the plugin root, so no leading '/':

```java
exitAction.setImageDescriptor(Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/download.png"));
```

Your plugin containing the advisor code must have an `icons` folder containing the `download.png` image.

Your `build.properties` file must include the `icons` folder in the build.